# No of occurances of a string in column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table as follows

```
Test

id     name
------------
1      test,ttt,test,iii,test
```

I want to find how many times the word test is appeared in the string.

when i pass the input as test,iii then i want the result like

```
test   3
iii    1
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: does `testest` get you a count of 1 or 2 then?

Comment: You cannot do it in `mySQL` unless you do `FULLTEXT` index. But you could probably pass it to a hidden form and let `jquery` do the counting using `match` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND ((LENGTH(name)- LENGTH(REPLACE(name, "test", "")))/LENGTH("test")) AS name
FROM Test;
```

Comment: if i have group of words to be searched how i can use group by for this

Comment: Can you explain in your question what exactly you want?

Comment: unfortunately this will not count as OP expects (as explained in the comments, `testest` should give count 2 not 1)

Comment: My answer will according to OP question provided with sample data.